# Kubernetes : How to delete a specific pod managed by StatefulSet without it being recreated?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a StatefulSet with 2 pods. It has a headless service and each pod has a LoadBalancer service that makes it available to the world.

Let's say pod names are pod-0 and pod-1.

If I want to delete pod-0 but keep pod-1 active, I am not able to do that.

I tried

```
kubectl delete pod pod-0
```

This deletes it but then restarts it because StatefulSet replica is set to 2.

So I tried

```
kubectl delete pod pod-0
kubectl scale statefulset some-name --replicas=1
```

This deletes pod-0, deletes pod-1 and then restarts pod-0. I guess because when replica is set to 1, StatefulSet wants to keep pod-0 active but not pod-1.

But how do I keep pod-1 active and delete pod-0?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why does "pod-0" not existing really matter?

Comment: Each pod holds specific data created by a user. Hence the stateful set. I want to store all the data created by a user and serve it back the next time the user needs it. When one user has created many pods or many users have created many pods, I want to be able to shut down any arbitrary pod based on user request.

Comment: One way out of this would be to create a StatefulSet with replica count 1 for each pod. This would ensure any pod can be removed based on user request and still preserve the persistent volume behind it. But that would mean a lot of StatefulSets to manage ..a bit inefficient I thought.

Comment: one way is set it with persistant volume, the other way is to set Redis or other cache solution. So you never mind to lost any pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by the StatefulSet controller. Probably the best you could do is try to create that pod yourself with a sleep shim and maybe you could be faster. But then the sts controller will just be unhappy forever.

Comment: What's a sleep shim? What about creating a new StatefulSet with replica count 1 to host each pod? That way any pod can be deleted independently. But it doesnt scale well. Too many statefulsets

Comment: It sounds like your use case does not match that of stateful sets. There isn't much difference between a Deployment and Sts for 1 replica.

Comment: The answer from @vaizki below is more complete.
You can "halt" the auto creating/update of pods owned by StatefulSets by deleting the StatefulSet with cascade orphan and recreating after you have done what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you `kubectl delete` the StatefulSet but add the `--cascade=orphan` option, the StatefulSet will be deleted but the Pods will remain. Then you can kill them in any order you want. When you recreate the StatefulSet it should adopt the remaining Pod(s) and create new ones to replace the missing ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a custom controller like:
https://github.com/openkruise/kruise/

You can have more fine grain control with selective pod removal, if you use a `CloneSet` custom resource.

```
apiVersion: apps.kruise.io/v1alpha1
kind: CloneSet
spec:
  # ...
  replicas: 4
  scaleStrategy:
    podsToDelete:
    - sample-9m4hp # you select which pod to remove
```

https://openkruise.io/en-us/docs/cloneset.html

The issue of removing specific pods of a `deployment` or `StatefulSet` has been opened for years with no resolution:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45509

Answer (score 0):

- Statefulset always creates the pods with indices 0..(replica-1).
- If you really want to have a finer control over individual pods, i guess you would need to create separate STS objects (with replica = 1)

Answer (score 0):

ReplicaSet in K8s 1.21+ will have `PodDeletionCost` POD annotation to solve that issue for Deployments but so far nothting for STS.